# How to Filter and get last entry based on date using C# and Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

This is a snippet of the json document which has records of card swipes of multiple students in different departments. Each student will have multiple entries based on when they enter the classrooms. The query needs to get the latest based on a list of student ids and department name.

```
{ 
[
 {
      "studentid"; "stu-1234",
      "dept" : "geog",
      "teacher_id" : 1, 
      "Carddetails": 
     { 
        "LastSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T10:50:00.5230694Z"
     }
 },

 {
      "studentid"; "stu-1234",
      "dept" : "geog",
      "teacher_id" : 2, 
      "Carddetails": 
     { 
        "LastSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T11:50:00.5230694Z"
     }
 },
 {
      "studentid"; "stu-abc",
      "dept" : "geog",
      "teacher_id" : 11, 
      "Carddetails": 
     { 
        "LastSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T09:15:00.5230694Z"
     }
 },
 {
      "studentid"; "stu-abc",
      "dept" : "geog",
      "teacher_id" : 21, 
      "Carddetails": 
     { 
        "LastSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T11:30:00.5230694Z"
     }
 }
]
}
```

From the data above the query needs to get `studentID: stu-abc` and `stu-1234` from the `geog` department based on their last card swiped timestamp. In this case it would be
`stu-abc: 2021-11-25T11:30:00.5230694Z` and `stu-1234:2021-11-25T11:50:00.5230694Z` respectively.

This is my code so far

```
string [] students = {'stu-abc', 'stu-1234'}
string dept = "geog";
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("studentid", students )
                    & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("dept", dept);

_collections.Find(filter).Sort(Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("{\"LastSwipeTimestamp\":-1}")).FirstOrDefault()
```

But this only gets me one record `stu-1234:2021-11-25T11:50:00.5230694Z`

How do I get both?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` always returns one item or `null` if the collection is empty. If you remove that and use `ToList` instead, what results do you get?

Comment: That gives all rows

Comment: This requires an aggregation grouping on students - first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your requirement, I think the Aggregation pipeline is more suitable.

```
[{
    $match: {
        "studentid": {
            "$in": [
                "stu-abc",
                "stu-1234"
            ]
        },
        "dept": "geog"
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "Carddetails.LastSwipeTimestamp": -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "studentid": "$studentid",
            "dept": "$dept"
        },
        "Carddetails": {
            $first: "$Carddetails"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "studentid": "$_id.studentid",
        "dept": "$_id.dept",
        "Carddetails": "$Carddetails"
    }
}]
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6KXwN0Fbc5Y)

---

Convert MongoDB query to Mongo .NET Driver will be as below:

```cs
string[] students = { "stu-abc", "stu-1234" };
string dept = "geog";

var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$match",
    new BsonDocument
    {
        { "studentid",
            new BsonDocument("$in",
                BsonArray.Create(students))
            },
            { "dept", dept }
        }),
    new BsonDocument("$sort",
    new BsonDocument("Carddetails.LastSwipeTimestamp", -1)),
    new BsonDocument("$group",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id",
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "studentid", "$studentid" },
                    { "dept", "$dept" }
                } 
            },
            { "Carddetails",
                new BsonDocument("$first", "$Carddetails") 
            }
        }
    ),
    new BsonDocument("$project",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", 0 },
            { "studentid", "$_id.studentid" },
            { "dept", "$_id.dept" },
            { "Carddetails", "$Carddetails" }
        }
    )
};

var result = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline)
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Hi Yong. Thanks for your reply. How do you learn how to construct this C#? Is there some documentation around this for C#? I dont understand why I need to put the `_id` field after the `$group` keyword ... ` new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id",`

Comment: Also, if I need to add more fields to the original json like say teacher_Id, how should that be factored in?

Comment: updated the question with additional details..

Comment: Hi, $group requires _id, which this _id is used as the key for grouping. If you have MongoDB Compass, you can chek this [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/export-query-to-language/) that it supports conversion the query to programming language, like C#.

Comment: For other fields like teacher_id, I assume this field is not used as grouping right? If yes, you can check out this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QnGJwxocRiE), with `$$ROOT`.